# 0.003006 ACPI: Unable to load the system description tables Acer F5-571

Tags: boot, uefi, acer, bios

I have been trying to install Ubuntu on my Acer F5-571 with no success!.. when trying to install in UEFI mode i get a black screen when i select any option and when in legacy mode i get 0.003006 ACPI: Unable to load the system description tables. 
I have looked up this error and its to do with bios 1.25 for acer laptops but my laptop has no alternative bios to be updated or downgraded to.

Does anyone know of a work around or solution ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update 2016-01-20**. Danixu86 [link](http://community.acer.com/t5/Legacy-Laptops-and-Netbooks/BIOS-F5-571-UEFI-Linux-Ubuntu/m-p/409481#M67203) reports that the latest BIOS version 1.35 for the F5-571 solves the problem so it's no longer necessary to downgrade.

Fortunately there is an answer to your problem and it is relatively easy to use. I have tried it and it works very well. I am very grateful to Danixu86 and slowfoobar for providing the answers.

**1. BIOS**

In order to allow booting from a Live DVD or USB (not just Ubuntu) you need to downgrade the BIOS. Although Acer does not provide one for the F5-571, it turns out that the BIOS is identical to the one for the E5-573G.

Here are the instructions for doing so, slightly adapted from slowfoobar's post at [Acer Aspire e5-573g. You can not install any one Linux distributi​on. The problem BIOS 1.25](http://community.acer.com/t5/E-and-M-Series/Acer-Aspire-e5-573g-You-can-not-install-any-one-Linux/m-p/386281#M3080).
I realise that changing the BIOS is scary but it does work well for me and a number of other users (see link in 2. below)

> Go to Acer's Support site for your country
>
> Search by Product Model:
>
> Aspire E5-573G
>
> Select the right OS and download a bios. In my case I downloaded 1.15.
>
> Run the ZRT_115.exe.
>
> It will fail.
>
> But before you close the installer, go to
>   C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Temp\
>
> Search for a folder (random letters).tmp
>
> There should be a H2OFFT-W.exe and zrt.rd file in there.
>
> Just copy this folder and close the failing install.
>
> In that copied folder, edit the platform.ini file.
>
> Before:

```
[BIOSVersionFormat] 
;[nb4-version] + 
BIOSVFEnable=1
VersionFormat=XN.NN
```

> After:

```
[BIOSVersionFormat] 
;[nb4-version] + 
BIOSVFEnable=1
VersionFormat=XN.DD
```

> The VersionFormat value now has 'XN.DD' instead of 'XN.NN'.
>
> This will ignore the fact that 1.25 -> 1.15 is a downgrade.
>
> Prepare for a reboot. I.E. close unnecessary applications. Because
>   it'll happen automatically after running the installer.
>
> Run H2OFFT-W.exe.
>
> Upon reboot, you'll see a bios installing progress bar.
>
> After that is done, press F2 during startup to get to bios. The
>   version should now be 1.15.

**2. Dual Booting Linux and Windows**

These are Danixu86's instructions taken from [BIOS, F5-571, UEFI, Linux / Ubuntu](http://community.acer.com/t5/Legacy-Laptops-and-Netbooks/BIOS-F5-571-UEFI-Linux-Ubuntu/m-p/400944#M66526). You may wish to read the rest of the thread to see other user's experiences.

> - You've to downgrade the bios using the above link. Don't care if the laptop model is different.
> - Change the touchpad mode to basic on BIOS.
> - Install your prefered Linux version and enjoy.
>
> Next we will do is add the grub files to "trusted boot". For that we
>   will go to "Security" tab > "Select a UEFI file as trusted for
>   executing" and select the "grubx64.efi" file. Later we will see the
>   Grub boot on Bios order and we will be able to set as the first place:
>
> [image: índice.jpg]
>
> With that steps finally the Clonezilla has booted and i've done a full
>   hard drive backup without problems and i've installed the Ubuntu
>   14.04.3 version.

**3. Making wifi work**

This is taken from Danixu86's instructions at the same place

> To make the wifi works you have to open a terminal as root and run
>   this commands:

```
# wget http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/backports/2015/11/20/backports-20151120.tar.xz
# tar -xvf backports-20151120.tar.xz 
# cd backports-20151120
# make defconfig-ath10k
# make
# make install

# apt-get install git
# git clone https://github.com/kvalo/ath10k-firmware.git
# cd ath10k-firmware/
# cp -R QCA9377 /lib/firmware/ath10k/
# ln -s /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-5.bin_WLAN.TF.1.0-00267-1 /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-2.bin
```

> Just reboot and you will get the wifi working.
>
> Maybe it will work with other linux versions too because we are
>   compiling the source.
>
> Some distributions may need "Build Essentials tools" to build the wifi
>   source: apt-get install build-essential
>
> The only problem (at least on Ubuntu) is that reboot did not work, you
>   have to shutdown the computer and then power on again.
>
> EDIT: I've reinstalled Ubuntu again to test the exact above steps and
>   now reboot is working fine too.

Comment: Update. Danixu86 [link](http://community.acer.com/t5/Legacy-Laptops-and-Netbooks/BIOS-F5-571-UEFI-Linux-Ubuntu/m-p/409481#M67203) reports that the latest BIOS version 1.35 for the F5-571 solves the problem so it's no longer necessary to downgrade.

Comment: Could you edit that information into your answer (maybe at the top separated from the rest of the answer, so that it's more visible)?